# Simplifying product of two modified Bessel functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, bessel-functions

Is it possible to simplify the product of two modified Bessel functions of the first kind with order zero,
\begin{align}
\Bigg( \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{ \Big( \frac{x^{2}}{4} \Big)^{n} }{n! \cdot n!} \Bigg) \cdot \Bigg( \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{ \Big( \frac{x^{2}}{4} \Big)^{k} }{k! \cdot k!} \Bigg) \text{?}
\end{align}

I have gotten as far as
\begin{align}
& \Bigg( \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{ \Big( \frac{x^{2}}{4} \Big)^{n} }{n! \cdot n!} \Bigg) \cdot \Bigg( \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{ \Big( \frac{x^{2}}{4} \Big)^{k} }{k! \cdot k!} \Bigg) \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \Big( \frac{x^{2}}{4} \Big)^{n} \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{1}{k! \cdot k!} \cdot \frac{1}{(n-k)! \cdot (n-k)!} \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{ \Big( \frac{x^{2}}{4} \Big)^{n} }{n! \cdot n!} \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k}^{2} \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{2n}{n}^{2} \cdot \dfrac{ \Big( \frac{x}{2} \Big)^{2n}}{(2n)!} \text{;}
\end{align}
however, I cannot see a way forward. If possible, I'd like to represent the product in terms of another modified Bessel function, beyond the very obvious definition already given above. Perhaps the [exponential generating function of the central binomial coefficients](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3210839/the-exponential-generating-function-for-the-central-binomial-coefficients) could be useful.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** The  sequence  of squared central   binomial coefficients $\left(\binom{2n}{n}^2\right)_{n\geq 0}=(1,4,36,400,4\,900, 63\,504,\ldots)$ is stored as *[A002894](https://oeis.org/A002894)* in OEIS.

Since  there  is  no further exponential generating series given besides $\text{BesselI}(0, 2x)^2=\left(\sum_{n\geq 0}\binom{2n}{n}\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}\right)^2$ we rather do not expect another essentially different representation via Bessel functions.